# Unity Facebook SDK: Stay logged in

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I do have a question: I am trying to connect my Unity game with Facebook, which works fine. I am able to get the user's profile picture after he/she clicks on "connect with Facebook". However, if I restart the Scene in the editor I have to reconnect to Facebook again in order to retrieve the profile picture.

How is it possible to keep a user connected to Facebook and get e.g. the profile picture once the scene Starts (in Start())?

Games like Candy crush saga can do it automatically but I just can't figure out how.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want it to work in editor xor on device?

Comment: In real device it keeps connected. It's editor issue.

Comment: Hey, on my device. However, I will need to test it so ... Just to be clear: I initialize Facebook, a user connects to Facebook and I get the profile picture through the API. But how do I get it without the user pressing on the "connect to Facebook" button? I just want the user to do it on the first start of my App. I am lacking some basic knowledge on how that is handled on Unity's Facebook SDK. Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution to this ?